# PouchDB detect documents that aren't synced

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to sync a local PouchDB instance to a remote CouchDB.  Things work great, but I am not sure how to deal with the following situation:

I have added a validation rule in CouchDB to prevent updating (it will deny all updates).  When I run the sync function on my local PouchDB instance after modifying a document, the "denied" event fires as I would expect.  However, if I run sync a second time, the "denied" event doesn't fire again, even though the local document differs from the CouchDB version.

How can I check if the local database matches the remote database?  If I miss the "denied" event the first time (lets say the user closes the browser), how can I detect on the next run that the databases are not in sync?  How can I force PouchDB to try and sync the modified document again so that I can see the denied event?

Thanks!

```
syncPouch: function(){
  var opts = {};
  var sync = PouchDB.sync('orders', db.remoteDB, opts);
  sync.on('change', function (info) {});
  sync.on('paused', function(){
  });
  sync.on('active', function () {});
  sync.on('denied', function(err){
    //This only fire once no matter how many times I call syncPouch
    console.log("Denied!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    debugger;
  });
  sync.on('complete', function (info) {
    //This fires every time
    console.log("complete");console.log(info);
  });
  sync.on('error', function(err){
    debugger;
  });
  return sync;
},
```

Answer (score 2):

What I have noticed with validate_doc_update functions is that PouchDb appears to treat any "denied" document as sync-ed. So even if you then remove the validate_doc_update function, the document will not sync into the remote database on future attempts *even though it is not the same*.

So you can be left with an "out of sync" situation that can only be fixed by editing one of the documents again.

Perhaps you are seeing the same thing? Perhaps the "denied" event does not fire because there is no attempt by PouchDb to sync the document (as it has already attempted to sync it previously)?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and yes I think you're right. Pouch counts a "denied" document as synced and forgets about it. Is there some flag you can set in the handler to update the document so it's tried again? Or is it up to the application to keep track of these failures and ensure the client updates the record before an attempt is made to sync it again.

Comment: I discovered later this is to do with "checkpoints". 

In the replication API, there is an advanced option to turn off checkpoints - this means that the replication will look at ALL documents, not just those that changed since the checkpoint was written during the last replication event.

Have a look at the PouchDB guide on replication: 

https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication

Comment: Thanks IanC, i actually experimented with the checkpoint setting and found it didn't help things much for me, but ultimately I think my problem was actually caused by the implementation of couch DB I'm using (Drupal relaxed/replication modules), because even though it was reporting errors trying to save entities it was still writing records to the couchdb index. - so the server thought the data was correct when in reality it had failed to complete the write.